# Зачем PyCharm исключает venv?

Tags: pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем PyCharm исключает venv? (С excluded venv Я могу импортировать библиотеки наводясь на объект, а без excluded не могу. Как это работает? )